# Error: Could not stat device devsdb - No such file or directory

Tags: partitioning, fdisk, parted

Setting up an ubuntu server for the first time. It loads up just fine but when I try to partition my 2.7T drive it's giving me the following error:

```
fdisk: cannot open devsda: No such file or directory
root@devinserver:/home/devin# lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0 7:0 0 89.1M 1 loop /snap/core/8268
loop1 7:1 0 120.4M 1 loop /snap/docker/423
loop2 7:2 0 218.4M 1 loop /snap/nextcloud/20007
loop3 7:3 0 55M 1 loop /snap/core18/1705
loop4 7:4 0 3.5M 1 loop /snap/stress-ng/2474
loop5 7:5 0 93.8M 1 loop /snap/core/8935
sda 8:0 0 111.8G 0 disk
├─sda1 8:1 0 512M 0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2 8:2 0 111.3G 0 part /
sdb 8:16 0 2.7T 0 disk
sr0 11:0 1 1024M 0 rom

# parted \dev\sdb mklabel gpt
Error: Could not stat device devsdb - No such file or directory.
Retry/Cancel? ^C

# fdisk \dev\sdb
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.

Be careful before using the write command.  

fdisk: cannot open devsdb: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This appears to be a simple typographical error in your command `parted \dev\sdb mklabel gpt`. The path separators should be forward slashes not backslashes: `parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt`